# What is preventing Firefox from deleting active logins/cookies on exit?

Tags: windows-7, macos, firefox, cookies

Alright, so I want Firefox to delete all active logins/cache when I close it. My privacy settings are:

```
Accept cookies from sites
    Accept third-party cookies: Always
    Keep until: I close Firefox
    [Show Exceptions] is empty
Clear history when Firefox closes
    Cookies
    Active logins
    Cache
```

Obviously, this didn't work. I closed Firefox, reopened it, and I'm still logged into all my websites. So I decided, the hell with it, I'll add cookies to be cleared when Firefox closes...

And sure enough, it didn't delete any of my cookies when I re-opened it! It logged me back into all of my websites. What could be causing this behavior? I'm running Firefox 36.0.4 and I have the same behavior on both Windows 7 and Mac OS X 10.10.

Here's what it is currently:

[image: Privacy Settings]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure you have `Cookies` ticked under the `History` heading in the Settings panel beside `Clear history when Firefox closes`. If it still doesn't work, maybe try ticking `Site Preferences` and `Offline Website Data` in the same panel under the heading `Data` ?

Comment: Did this answer solve your question? I would love feedback.